# mkisofs error - boot image...efibot.img not an allowable size

Tags: linux, rhel, iso, mkisofs

I am trying to create a custom ISO from a rhel-8 installation disk that can boot on either a BIOS or an EFI server.  Everything goes fine until I try to create the iso.  If I run the following command:

```
mkisofs -J -R -T -V "NGS-8.4-0 Server" \
    -o ngs-8.4-0.iso \
    -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
    -c isolinux/boot.cat \
    --no-emul-boot \
    --boot-load-size 4 \
    --boot-info-table \
    --eltorito-alt-boot \
    -e images/efiboot.img \
    -m TRANS.TBL \
    ngs-dvd
```

I get the following output:

```
Creating NGS iso...I: -input-charset not specified, using iso-8859-1 (detected in locale settings)

(bunch of TRANS.TBL output deleted)

Size of boot image is 4 sectors -> No emulation
Size of boot image is 19612 sectors -> genisoimage: Error - boot image '/NGS/ngs-dvd/images/efiboot.img' has not an allowable size.
```

However, if I delete two options (`--eltorito-alt-boot` & `-e images/efiboot.img`), it creates a bootable iso.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/357512/why-is-my-linux-reporting-an-allowable-size-error-when-building-an-iso/359247

Comment: @pbies I l already read that.  It didn't help since I already had the 3 options that answer said should be added `no-emul-boot`, `boot-load-size`, and `boot-into-table`.  And, the command works if I only try to make a BIOS only bootable iso.

Comment: Then: https://askubuntu.com/questions/625286/how-to-create-uefi-bootable-iso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that I needed the `-no-emul-boot` option twice.  One for each boot image (BIOS & EFI).  The final working configuration was:

```
/usr/bin/mkisofs -J -R -T -V "NGS-8.4-0 Server" \
    -o ngs-8.4-0.iso \
    -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
    -c isolinux/boot.cat \
    -no-emul-boot \
    -boot-load-size 4 \
    -boot-info-table \
    -eltorito-alt-boot \
    -e images/efiboot.img \
    -no-emul-boot \
    -m TRANS.TBL \
    ngs-dvd
```

Comment: you made my day. with this I was finally able to make an iso file almost as original. Start is `33 ed 90` instead of `45 52 08` and https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/11285.html hints me Apple support is missing. When have you got `-e` option from? It is not in man page (at least on my system). Also have not found it on https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs.

Comment: @Martian2020 I don't remember exactly where I got it.  I looked at so many web pages describing how to make a bootable iso that they are all a blur.  However, it is in my man page for mkisofs(1):  `-e efi_boot_file  Set EFI boot image name.`
`

Answer (score 3):

From man page:

> -eltorito-alt-boot
> Start with **a new set** of El Torito boot **parameters**.  Up to 63 El Torito boot entries may be stored on a single CD.

So the finding in your answer that you need to add `-no-emul-boot` again after `-eltorito-alt-boot` means EFI image added by `-e` also need `-no-emul-boot` to work properly and as it is next El Torito entry and starts with new set of parameters, needed parameters need to be explicitly listed again.

From the question:

> However, if I delete two options (--eltorito-alt-boot & -e
> images/efiboot.img), it creates a bootable iso.

I've done that way initially too, it created iso that resulted in legacy boot only (no EFI, `-e` adds part that becomes EFI partition on USB later).

BTW, before writing to USB `isohybrid --uefi new.iso` command is needed.

There appears to be good related post+discussion [Anatomy of a Fedora 17 ISO image](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/11285.html), I have not read it all yet.

P.S. why many other options are critical (e.g. no size except 4 seems to work out) I have not been able to find out (as of now). `-e` option appears to be absent in man pages on my system, but works. https://wiki.osdev.org/Mkisofs:

> -e ISOPATH announces a data file as El Torito boot image for EFI. This is not an option of original mkisofs, but is understood by some
> variants of genisoimage and by xorriso -as mkisofs.